# How to configure postfix to not relay to local virtual domain?

Tags: 14.04, server, dns, email, postfix

I have set up a SMTP server with iRedMail on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and everything is working smoothly. I can create new users and send e-mails.

My situation however is a bit more complicated: I need this server to send e-mails on behalf of my domain name "sampledomain.xxx" but I'm using a hosted mail service to receive e-mails. My domain DNS's MX records are set to a different IP than the SMTP server I've just set up. Basically this should be an outgoing-only SMTP server.

The problem arises when I need to use the SMTP server as user1@sampledomain.xxx to user2@sampledomain.xxx because Postfix thinks that mail should be relayed internally, but it doesn't find the address in the virtual domain's mailboxes and thus fail to send the e-mail.

How can I configure Postfix to not relay internally such e-mails and instead resolve MX records and send them as classic e-mails?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Open your postfix configuration file (usually `/etc/postfix/main.cf`) in a text editor.  I like `vim`.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Find the line where `mydestination` is set.  It probably looks something like this:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

Comment that line out by prefixing it with a `#`.

```
# mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

Add the following line and then save the file.

```
mydestination =
```

Restart postfix

```
$ service postfix stop
$ service postfix start
```

Postfix will no longer try to deliver 'local' email to this server but will use the SMTP server given by the DNS MX record.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't an accepted answer, less still why it was downvoted - worked for me, except I just had to remove just one domain from the list rather than the whole list.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, I'm glad it worked for you. I've never understood down votes without explanation. Some people just don't seem to get it.

Comment: That worked for me. It should definitely be considered as right answer.

Comment: +1 from me ;-) Only needed to remove the $myhostname from the string, but I suppose technically commenting the whole line should be fine as there are no local mailboxes.

Comment: Does not work for me. I`m trying to send email from mail2.domain.com to mail.domain.com. The user only exists in mail.domain.com and mail2.domain.com is not defined in DNS MX records.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to exclude only $mydomain from mydestination list, i.e:
    mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
in case your hostname was .sampledomain.xxx
This setup would still allow receive local system notifications, such as root